# Are there equipment entries somewhere for calligraphy pens, paintbrushes, or other art tools?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

I don't own every single book, but a quick look at D20PFSRD seems to only show the inkpen. The closest I can think of is Artisan's Tools, which I suppose would work for pottery or sculpture, or the vague "Masterwork Tool" which I suppose might be recorded as "masterwork paintbrush". If there are entries for this sort of thing somewhere, I'd love to know the reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the *Core Rulebook*:

> All crafts require artisan's tools to give the best chance of success... masterwork artisan's tools provide a +2 circumstance bonus on the check.

For making calligraphy itself, you're right- it's pretty much artisan's tools or nothing. If you're not looking for items specifically for making a Craft (calligraphy) check, however, might I recommend the [following selection?](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/books-paper-writing-supplies/)